# Using Node js in Multiplayer turn based game in ios

Tags: ios, node.js, real-time, multiplayer, gkturnbasedmatch

Hope u guys are doing great.
I want to make a realtime turn based game in iOS .
I know this can be achieved by using GAME CENTRE in iOS , but i have to play this between browser and iOS app. WEB TEAM is using node js for making this game on web browser , they also suggested me to use node js in iOS game as well.

Have anyone has idea how to use node js for this kind of purpose.
Thanking you  all! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have websocket server written in node js and then just connect to it from your ios app using some websocket library (hope it exists). Then sockets connected from browser and your app can realtime exchange information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pub/sub messaging service like Realtime (the company I work for) http://framework.realtime.co/messaging/

Both your node.js server and your ios devices could exchange data through Realtime pub/sub channels, using the node.js and ios SDKs.

The cool part is that since it's a managed service you don't need to worry about the server and networking administration, Realtime will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add some words in favor of @Edgar's answer.

For production, using only WebSocket is not reliable. In environment where WebSocket is not available due to antivirus, enterprise firewall, and so on, a kind of full duplex connection over HTTP should be available utilizing long polling or streaming in terms of reliable real-time connection.

Also such connection might be disconnected for a while e.g. moving away from Wi-Fi zone and then some messages which had to send through that connection may be lost so that a way to recover such messages is required e.g. here is some messages you couldn't receive.

Therefore, you need a reliable framework to write such real-time web application. Here's [features](http://cettia.io/blog/cettia-1-0-0-alpha1-released/) which are required to write a real-time web application I think. (It's called Cettia and I'm the author of that project. As it doesn't provide iOS client, it's not right choice for you here. Just focus on features and roadmap to see what features you may be needed and evaluate a framework you will choose based on them.)

On Node.js world, socket.io framework has a great community so I'm sure someone already wrote iOS client for socket.io. Anyway, make sure that the framework you finally chose has features you need to write your real-time webapp.